# Android: Gradle always fails to compile Kotlin module

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project where I have added a kotlin project as module dependency. I always get this error while building and it is always failing. Below is the gradle error log

> 18:13:35.254 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE:
>   Build completed with 2 failures. 18:13:35.254 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  18:13:35.254
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 1:
>   Task failed with an exception. 18:13:35.254 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] -----------
>   18:13:35.254 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went
>   wrong: 18:13:35.254 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution
>   failed for task ':mykotlinModule:compileReleaseKotlin'. 18:13:35.254
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] >
>   Compilation error. See log for more details 18:13:35.255 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  18:13:35.255
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] *
>   Try: 18:13:35.255 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  Run with
>   --scan to get full insights. 18:13:35.255 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  18:13:35.255
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] *
>   Exception is: 18:13:35.255 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':myKotlinModule:compileReleaseKotlin'. 18:13:35.255 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>   18:13:35.255 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
>   18:13:35.255 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>   18:13:35.256 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
>   18:13:35.256 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>   18:13:35.256 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.execute(ResolveBuildCacheKeyExecuter.java:66)
>   18:13:35.256 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>   18:13:35.256 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>   18:13:35.256 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>   18:13:35.256 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>   18:13:35.256 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>   18:13:35.256 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>   18:13:35.256 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>   18:13:35.257 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>   18:13:35.257 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>   18:13:35.257 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
>   18:13:35.257 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
>   18:13:35.257 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
>   18:13:35.257 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
>   18:13:35.257 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>   18:13:35.257 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>   18:13:35.257 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
>   18:13:35.257 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
>   18:13:35.257 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:273)
>   18:13:35.258 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:258)
>   18:13:35.258 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
>   18:13:35.258 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
>   18:13:35.258 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
>   18:13:35.258 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
>   18:13:35.258 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
>   18:13:35.258 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>   18:13:35.258 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>   18:13:35.258 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   18:13:35.258 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by:
>   org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more
>   details 18:13:35.258 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:14)
>   18:13:35.259 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:121)
>   18:13:35.259 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:144)
>   18:13:35.259 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:139)
>   18:13:35.259 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvmCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:79)
>   18:13:35.259 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:449)
>   18:13:35.259 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:359)
>   18:13:35.259 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.executeImpl(Tasks.kt:316)
>   18:13:35.259 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:288)
>   18:13:35.259 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>   18:13:35.259 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
>   18:13:35.259 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>   18:13:35.259 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>   18:13:35.260 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
>   18:13:35.260 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
>   18:13:35.260 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
>   18:13:35.260 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
>   18:13:35.260 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>   18:13:35.260 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>   18:13:35.260 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
>   18:13:35.260 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
>   18:13:35.260 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  ... 32 more
>   18:13:35.260 [ERROR]
>   [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]  18:13:35.260
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]

Anybody has faced this issue? Please help

Comment: "Compilation error. See log for more details": what's the compilation error you are getting?